# Rewrite rule for pagination adds original url to the end

Tags: php, wordpress

I am rewriting my pagination URLs like so:

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    '([^/]+)/seite-([0-9])',
    'index.php?taxonomy=rubrik&term=$matches[1]&post_type=beitrag&paged=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

This works great and I can access paginated archives using the new URL. However, it also adds the original URL to the end so I end up with urls like that:

```
https://site.url/taxonomy/seite-3/page/3
```

However, I want it to be just:

```
https://site.url/taxonomy/seite-3
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe try updating `([^/]+)/seite-([0-9])` to `^([^/]+)/seite-([0-9])?$`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: The issue is with rewriting or URL construction? If rewriting please provide the URL you are trying to map.

Comment: Did you rewrite the original rule before the paging one as well? Look at the last comment in that link [add_rewrite_rule - working fine but broken for pagination](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163141/add-rewrite-rule-working-fine-but-broken-for-pagination)